# storing ints from a file separated /t and new lines

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I have a file called text.txt and it consists of coordinates:

```
<x value> <tab> <y value> 
<x value> <tab> <y value>
<x value> <tab> <y value>
...
```

I want to store them into array x[ ] and y[ ].
How do I use Scanner to store those ints.
THANK YOU!

Comment: Where is your code that you tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic example could be like this. Find more information in the [Oracle tutorial on scanning and formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            x.add(scanner.nextInt());
            y.add(scanner.nextInt());
            scanner.nextLine();

        }
    }
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}
```